# Finding likelihood for an event using Bayesian Inference

Tags: probability, bayesian

A spacecraft carrying two female and three male astronauts makes a trip toMars.
The plan calls for a two-person detachable capsule to land at site A on the planet
and a second one-person capsule to land at site B. The other two astronauts
remain in orbit. Which three will board the two capsules is decided by a lottery,
consisting of picking names from a box.

What is the probability that a female
occupies the one-person capsule if we know that at least one member of the other
capsule is female, but we are not told the order in which the astronauts were
picked?

This is a problem from chapter 4 of [this](http://www.cambridge.org/US/academic/subjects/statistics-probability/statistics-physical-sciences-and-engineering/bayesian-logical-data-analysis-physical-sciences-comparative-approach-mathematica-support) book. I have no clue how to approach this problem. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define events:

\begin{align}
A &= \text{At least one female in capsule } A \\
B &= \text{A female in capsule } B.
\end{align}

The probability required is:

\begin{align}
P(B\mid A) &= \dfrac{P(A\mid B)P(B)}{P(A)} \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{by Bayes Theorem} \\
&= \dfrac{(1-P(A^c\mid B))P(B)}{1-P(A^c)} \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (1)\\
\end{align}

Each of these required probabilities is easily calculated:

\begin{align}
P(A^c\mid B) &= \binom{3}{2} \bigg/ \binom{4}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2} \\
P(B) &= \dfrac{2}{5} \\
P(A^c) &= \binom{3}{2} \bigg/ \binom{5}{2} = \dfrac{3}{10}.
\end{align}

Substituting into $(1)$ gives:

$$P(B\mid A) = \dfrac{2}{7}.$$